# read int64 from fixed64 protobuf field in golang

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I have a field that is of type `fixed64` in a .proto file.

I want to read it as an int64 field:

```
score := int64(pb_obj.Score)
```

When I try to compile the line agove I get the error message `cannot convert pb_obj.Score (type *uint64) to type int64`.  I tried converting the a uint64 as well, and got an almost identical message.

Comment: Yes, *pb_obj.Score is fine. And also don't make sense to change fixed64 to int64. If score is allways positive use uint64 and fixed64 in proto. If can be negative prefer int64 and sfixed64 in proto files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pb_obj.Score`'s type seems to be `*uint64` (pointer to `uint64`), not `uint64`. You just need to access to the value the pointer is referencing:

```
score := int64(*pb_obj.Score)
```

(See the `*` prefix as the difference)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the compile error you're working with a uint64 pointer and not a uint64 value.  You may get what you want by referencing the value directly using the * operator. I've never worked with protobuf, so I could be off but that should get you moving.  Here's a nice reference that may help [golang pointers](https://www.golang-book.com/books/intro/8)